# NGINX - Redirecting works, proxy pass doesn't

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

So i'm trying to set up a reverse proxy and I've come across a weird error:
When I redirect the user everything works fine, but when I use proxy_pass (like I need) I get a "502 Bad Gateway error".

Code:

```
server { #banca empresas HTTP

            listen 80;

            server_name emp.baiq.pt www.emp.baiq.pt;

            rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;

    }

    server { #banca empresas HTTPS

            listen 443;

            server_tokens off;

            server_name emp.baiq.pt www.emp.baiq.pt;

            add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

            ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/*.baiteste.pt.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/*.baiteste.pt.key;

            location / {
                    #proxy_pass http://192.168.1.78:8081/login.htm?origin=E;
                    return 301 http://192.168.1.78:8081/login.htm?origin=E;
            }

            #error_page 500 502 503 504 /maintenance_page/index.html;

            location = /maintenance_page/index.html {
                    root html;
            }

            location = /favicon.ico {
                    log_not_found off;
            }

            access_log /var/log/nginx/emp.baiq.pt.access.log;

    }
```

After capturing traffic I found out that the peer, after the 3-way handshake is completed, immediately closes the connection once it receives the http-request.

So, what could be causing this error?

Error log file

```
2019/07/24 08:25:40 [error] 24506#24506: *2 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://y.y.y.y:8081/", host: domaintoaccess.com
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the peer's configuration? What does its log files tell?

Comment: Nothing conclusive. After checking the requests (access with proxy_pass and access with browser) they are exactly the same, only difference is the task numbers

Answer (score 0):

So after about 2 days of thinking about this (and with some help) I/we found out that it was a routing problem. The firewalls seem to be quietly dropping the packets for this communication for some reason (we don't have any rules that do this).